# Blower turns on before furnace ignites

Tags: furnace, blower

I have not relocated/changed the thermostat or had any work done on my furnace. The fans turn on well before the furnace starts giving off warm air, which blows a lot of cold air into my home. I have noticed that this happens when the temperature drops on the thermostat and does not happen when I push the temperature up manually. Also, the furnace cycles before the temperature drops to the next lowest degree on the thermostat setting. Any suggestions?

The furnace is an Ameristar M4PG4030A1060AA and the Thermostat is a PRO T701. They are both less than three years old. The clod air blows for a minute or two before the furnace starts. This has not happened until recently.

There is nothing flashing or any indication that there is something wrong on the outside of the unit. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please revise your post to tell us something about your furnace and thermostat.

Comment: Welcome and Thanks for posting, questions are better served if they contain as much details as possible. Make and model # of your furnace, details about the behavior etc. As much info as you can will help us to give you an informed answer.  **How do i ask a good question**.  > https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I there a panel on the furnace that has LED error codes flashing?   Here is the contact page from the Ameristar website. https://ameristarhvac.com/contact/#